# Display Current Friends

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am developing a Friend Request system and currently stuck at one point. I have two tables i.e. `member` and `requests`.  `requests` table stores `user_id` and `friend_id` of two users and I want to display names of current friends that are to be fetched from `member` table. For example, `request` table:

```
request_id | user_id(to) | friend_id(from) | status
2          | 2           | 3               | 1
3          | 3           | 1               | 1
6          | 4           | 2               | 1
7          | 2           | 1               | 1
```

I have achieved the current partners with the query below;

```
SELECT * FROM requests WHERE user_id='2' OR x.friend_id='2' AND x.status='1'
```

but all I can display for now are id's. What I am trying to achieve is getting the correct **names** according to the id's as well which are stored in the `member` table. Data stored in `member` table is;

```
member_id | name
1         | John
2         | Steve
3         | Sarah
4         | Stuart
```

So, if **id** no. 2 & 3 are friends, the **name** of the **added** friend should be displayed in user's profile who accepted the request.

What I am trying to do:

```
SELECT
    x.*,
    y.* 
FROM
    requests x,
    member y
WHERE 
    x.user_id='$member_id' OR 
    x.friend_id='$member_id' AND
    y.member_id = '$member_id' AND 
    x.status='1'
```

The result of this query gets a list of other members as well regardless of the `member_id` I'd specify. Can anybody please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Edit your question and add the schemas of the tables.

Comment: You should re-write using the more standard JOIN syntax.

Comment: I don't see where and how you're displaying the results or wanting to, including what the variables' values are if any, and what results you're getting now as opposed to the desired results. You didn't tell us much really, as well as the API used to connect with and if you even executed the query. I voted to close the question as unclear based on that.

Comment: Side notes: use parametrised queries with PDO or mysqli. And don't select `*` it'll cause potential issues in the future, and is a potential resource waste.

Comment: Please review the question now

Answer (score 0):

This should return the list you are looking for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM requests x
JOIN member y
    ON x.user_id = y.`member_id` OR x.friend_id = y.`member_id`
WHERE x.status = '1' AND y.member_id = '$member_id'
```

It works by using an inner join on the two tables, getting all of the rows that match the user_id or member_id, and then limiting the list to the is in $member_id.

Although you do not include any other code in your question, I suspect you are using PHP and mysqli to run this query. I would suggest using prepared queries instead of simple variable substitution so you can avoid SQL Injection.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name from member where user_id IN (select friend_id from request where user_id='$member_id' AND status=1);
```

Hope this will works!